# Pandas: slicing incompatible with numpy's

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, slice

I found a behavior in pandas that I'm not able to explain to myself.

I am studying a database of audio features with N+2 columns: an ID, the time `t`, and N audio features related to time `t`. For various reasons, I would like to put in every row also the features of the next T time steps. (yes, the same data will be repeated up to T times). I have therefore written a function that creates additional feature columns containing data from the successive time steps. I have implemented it in the three ways, as you can see in the attached code, and one of them is not working, which is surprising to me since it works if the underlying data structures are numpy arrays. Can anybody explain me why?

```
def create_datapoints_for_dnn(df, T):
    """
    Here we take the data frame with chroma features at time t and create all features at times t+1, t+2, ..., t+T-1.

    :param df: initial data frame of chroma features
    :param T: number of time steps to keep
    :return: expanded data frame of chroma features
    """
    res = df.copy()
    original_labels = df.columns.values
    n_steps = df.shape[0]  # the number of time steps in this song
    nans = pd.Series(np.full(n_steps, np.NaN)).values  # a column of nans of the correct length
    for n in range(1, T):
        new_labels = [ol + '+' + str(n) for ol in original_labels[2:]]
        for nl, ol in zip(new_labels, original_labels[2:]):
            # df.assign would use the name "nl" instead of what nl contains, so we build and unpack a dictionary
            res = res.assign(**{nl: nans})  # create a new column

            # CORRECT BUT EXTREMELY SLOW
            # for i in range(n_steps - (T - 1)):
            #     res.iloc[i, res.columns.get_loc(nl)] = df.iloc[n+i, df.columns.get_loc(ol)]

            # CORRECT AND FAST
            res.iloc[:-n, res.columns.get_loc(nl)] = df.iloc[:, df.columns.get_loc(ol)].shift(-n)

            # NOT WORKING
            # res.iloc[:-n, res.columns.get_loc(nl)] = df.iloc[n:, df.columns.get_loc(ol)]

    return res[: - (T - 1)]  # drop the last T-1 rows because time t+T-1 is not defined for them
```

Data example (put it in a csv):

```
songID,time,A_t,A#_t
CrossEra-0850,0.0,0.0,0.0
CrossEra-0850,0.1,0.0,0.0
CrossEra-0850,0.2,0.0,0.0
CrossEra-0850,0.3,0.31621,0.760299
CrossEra-0850,0.4,0.0,0.00107539
CrossEra-0850,0.5,0.0,0.142832
CrossEra-0850,0.6,0.8506459999999999,0.12481600000000001
CrossEra-0850,0.7,0.0,0.21206399999999997
CrossEra-0850,0.8,0.0796207,0.28227399999999997
CrossEra-0850,0.9,2.55144,0.169434
CrossEra-0850,1.0,3.4581699999999995,0.08014550000000001
CrossEra-0850,1.1,3.1061400000000003,0.030419599999999998
```

Code to run it

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

T = 4  # how many successive steps we want to put in a single row
df = pd.read_csv('path_to_csv')
res = create_datapoints_for_dnn(df, T)
res.to_csv('path_to_output', index=False)
```

Results:
[image: correct results]
[image: wrong results]

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.DataFrame.shift` and `concat`
f-string requires Python 3.6.  Otherwise use `'+{}'.format(i)'`

```
cols = ['songID', 'time']
d = df.drop(['songID', 'time'], 1)
df[cols].join(
    pd.concat(
        [d.shift(-i).add_suffix(f'+{i}') for i in range(4)],
        axis=1
    )
)

           songID  time     A_t+0    A#_t+0     A_t+1    A#_t+1     A_t+2    A#_t+2     A_t+3    A#_t+3
0   CrossEra-0850   0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.316210  0.760299
1   CrossEra-0850   0.1  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.316210  0.760299  0.000000  0.001075
2   CrossEra-0850   0.2  0.000000  0.000000  0.316210  0.760299  0.000000  0.001075  0.000000  0.142832
3   CrossEra-0850   0.3  0.316210  0.760299  0.000000  0.001075  0.000000  0.142832  0.850646  0.124816
4   CrossEra-0850   0.4  0.000000  0.001075  0.000000  0.142832  0.850646  0.124816  0.000000  0.212064
5   CrossEra-0850   0.5  0.000000  0.142832  0.850646  0.124816  0.000000  0.212064  0.079621  0.282274
6   CrossEra-0850   0.6  0.850646  0.124816  0.000000  0.212064  0.079621  0.282274  2.551440  0.169434
7   CrossEra-0850   0.7  0.000000  0.212064  0.079621  0.282274  2.551440  0.169434  3.458170  0.080146
8   CrossEra-0850   0.8  0.079621  0.282274  2.551440  0.169434  3.458170  0.080146  3.106140  0.030420
9   CrossEra-0850   0.9  2.551440  0.169434  3.458170  0.080146  3.106140  0.030420       NaN       NaN
10  CrossEra-0850   1.0  3.458170  0.080146  3.106140  0.030420       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
11  CrossEra-0850   1.1  3.106140  0.030420       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

​

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I already had a similar solution implement. The question was why the method `res.iloc[:-n, res.columns.get_loc(nl)] = df.iloc[n:, df.columns.get_loc(ol)]` is not working.

Comment: Because Pandas compares the values based on alignment of the indices.  You've done nothing to alter those indices.  Use `res.iloc[:-n, res.columns.get_loc(nl)] = df.iloc[n:, df.columns.get_loc(ol)].values`

Comment: If I understand correctly, df.iloc[n:] returns a df that is still indexed between n and N. This is unlike numpy, where for example `a = np.arange(10)[2:10][0]` is a complicated but perfectly valid mode of writing `a=2`. If numpy treated arrays the same way pandas treats data frames, the previous line will give `None` because the array `np.arange(10)[2:10]` only has elements with indices between 2 and 9 (included). Writing `.values` forces pandas to create a new dataframe with new indexing, therefore correcting the issue. Thank you. If you copy your comment in the answer I will accept it.